# Can't convert ProviderUserKey to GUID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, guid

Hi I am basically trying to create my own Facebook Login (and create a local account). I have everything working except this one bit: After creating the account I am trying to setup a basic profile and tie it back to the account. I am able to create the account but when I try to cast the providerkey to a Guid, it comes back null. If I try to not cast it I get the error "cannot implicitly convert object to Guid" The providerkeyvalue itself is not null and is in a format like this {7092216C-943F-4D30-9432-6CD10CF3447E}

```
// Attempt to register the user
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
Membership.CreateUser(fbprofile.first_name + fbprofile.id, GenerateRandomPassword(8), fbprofile.email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success) 
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(fbprofile.first_name + fbprofile.id); //Gotta get the GUID and tie it to the profile


    profile.UserID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
}else{
}
```

EDIT: If it makes a difference, the ProviderUserKey is set to just object in the membership class.

Comment: Are you using the SqlMembershipProvider? In that case your code should work (according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx). If not, what does user.ProviderUserKey.GetType() return, when adding it to a (quick-)watch window?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  If you cast user.ProviderUserKey to a guid (via a hard cast) then it won't return null, it will throw an exception if the value is null or not a guid.  A Guid is a value type, and cannot be null, so if you're finding that profile.UserID is null, it must be because it's a nullable type and you are setting it to null somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, your problem is that you are not creating an instance of the Profile class.  You cannot assign values to null objects without first creating an instance of that object.

"Object Reference not set to instance of object" means that you are trying to dereference a null object, that is you are trying to access a member or property of an object that is null.

On that line of code, there are only two things that will cause that error.  Either profile is null or user is null, if either of them are null, you will get this error.  That is the only thing it could possibly be.

Comment: Are you referring to the Standard Microsoft Profile class? I basically made a simple entity for mine.

Comment: @dreadlocks1221 - No, i'm talking about whatever class the variable in your code called profile is.

Comment: Ok you are right, the profile was null so I couldn't assign the GUID to it, although it is strange that it let me assign other fields before crashing on that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string to the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) of the Guid struct:

```
// user.ProviderUserKey == "{7092216C-943F-4D30-9432-6CD10CF3447E}"
profile.UserID = new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey);
```

The constructor accepts GUIDs in various formats, such as "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd", "dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd", "{dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd}" and more.

Comment: thanks but I still have the same problem, I also have to call ToString as dknaack suggested